# Stick a div above a bottom positioned div (absolute) with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I have some kind of chat where is a `textarea` with dynamic height positioned at the `bottom` of the chat box (a `div` with a non variable `height`), and above it should be the `.messages` `div`. `.messages` also have a variable height, and will eventually overflow the `.chat` container; then, an scrollbar should appear, just like (exactly like, actually) facebook's chat. I'm using the [Textarea-autosize](https://github.com/javierjulio/textarea-autosize) plugin on the textarea.

I'd make a code snippet, but I can't get the plugin to work here and my page is a mess and I don't know how that thing works, but it does, so I ain't gonna question its poor logic; maybe if I find out it shouldn't work it'll actually stop workin'. So, I'm gonna show off my terrible photoshop skills and try to show you what I mean:

[image][image]

The blue square would be the `.messages`

I was hoping there were a `CSS` only solution. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so from your question you are not very clear, which is probably why you received a downvote (not from me).

But from the image, I would say to use "margin-top: -30px" (or however many px you want) on the box on the right to move it up.

Try the CSS on the div container, or add an outside container to the `.messages` div and add the css to that container div.

However, without a clearer question and more details, I can't be much more help.